# Different solutions to wave equation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I know only about Plane wave solution and spherical wave solution to wave equation.

Are there other types of solution to wave equation?

Is spherical wave solution the most general solution? If yes, how do I confirm that it is most general solution?

Comment: I've found https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1009&context=foundation_wave to be helpful! Equation 9.25 is the general solution. Spherical waves are not the most general. A general solution can be thought of as a continuous superposition of plane waves.

Comment: Would "numerical" count as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a huge (infinite) array of different solutions of the three-dimensional wave equation $-$ so many that there is very little point in listing them all. There are plenty of special-functions solutions that have an 'exact' form in suitable coordinate systems (with the most obvious omission from your list being the Bessel-functions solution in cylindrical coordinates, but also including  a wide zoo detailed in e.g. p. 164 and p. 210 of [this pdf](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~mille003/3Dhelmholtz.pdf)), and they go up in painfulness as the intricacy of their associated coordinate system increases.

As for a *general* solution, take any of those families and form arbitrary linear combinations, and you'll get a general solution.

Comment: But how many of the 'huge (infinite) array of different solutions of the three-dimensional wave equation' will propagate without a wake and without a backward wave? i.e. obey Huygens' Principle?